# How did Kirio regain his memory?

Tags: ushio-to-tora

In episode 27 of *Ushio to Tora* (2015-16 version), we come to learn that Hakumen no Mono has used memory-altering *hiyou* to make almost everybody forget about Ushio and Tora (Jie Mei, Saya, Hyou, and Tokisaka/Tokijun are spared for various reasons).

In particular, in episode 27, we specifically see Kirio having lost his memories of Ushio and Tora. Then, in episode 29 (he doesn't appear in episode 28), we see that he's regained his memories of the two of them.

How did that happen? (The anime seems to be eliding a bunch of details in order to fit the rest of the story into this cour, and this seems like one of those things that would've been cut.)

Answer (score 1):

As seen in a later episode

> Kirio was actually travelling through time with Tokisaka while Hakumen no Mono sent out its minions to remove both Ushio and Tora from the memories of everyone they had contact with.

Comment: That doesn't sound quite right. Kirio had already been affected by Hakumen no Mono in episode 27; he didn't go back in time with Tokisaka until later. (I'm pretty sure you're right that the time-travelling had something to do with it, though.)

Comment: I see. I'll rewatch it then :D